# Web Analytics webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-analytics

Is there any way I can configure to get the analytics from different web application using Web analytics web part in SharePoint? This is needed because my search center is a different web application and client likes to show search analytics as dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do this with OOTB options.  You can however use a web viewer web part and "SharePoint Vitals" to get the experience you are looking for.

Comment: Welcome to sp.se. Can you explain "You can however use a web viewer web part and "SharePoint Vitals" to get the experience you are looking for." in greater detail please.